# using esp8266 to fetch specific data from firebase

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

I want to fetch specific data from firebase using Node Mcu ESP 8266. I can fetch the num value, but I failed to fetch the id value. The serial monitor kept displaying 0 when I try to fetch the id value. Any method to fetch the newest insert id value( Id value automatically update every time I submit the form at my web application). Thank you.

below is my coding

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <FirebaseArduino.h>


// Set these to run example.
#define FIREBASE_HOST "inserted"
#define FIREBASE_AUTH "inserted"
#define WIFI_SSID "Pro_4258"
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "1234567890"


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);


  // connect to wifi.
  WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);
  Serial.print("connecting");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(500);
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("connected: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  
  Firebase.begin(FIREBASE_HOST, FIREBASE_AUTH);
}
int a;


void loop() {


  a=Firebase.getInt("id");
  
  if (Firebase.failed())
  {
    Serial.println(Firebase.error());
    }else
    {
      Serial.println(a);
      }
delay(500);
}
```

[image: Firebase realtime database]